# How to transfer terabyte of data faster?

Tags: hard-drive, data-transfer, file-transfer, rsync

I have a terabyte of data to copy from old external HDD to new external HDD.
By the way the new hdd is encrypted via DiskUtility.
I'm using macbookpro,two hdd's and two apple's USB-C to USB Adapters for this transfer.
Is there a way to do it faster?I think,only ''preparing files'' will take day or two and copying will take 4-7 days.I can't afford such.

PS: I've read about `cp` and `rsync` but I'm not too familiar and I'm afraid I might get some of the switches wrong and miss files, or screw up the file dates, or worst...

Comment: Use rsync although get a newer version than Apple supplies

Comment: @mmmmmm I've read about CP and RSYNC but I'm not too familiar and I'm afraid I might get some of the switches wrong and miss files, or screw up the file dates, or worst...

Comment: Then use Carbon Copy Cloner

Comment: You mention USB adaptors. If that's to USB 2, then that will be your bottleneck, no matter what else you do.

Comment: Which specific Macbook model are you using? And are these HDDs or SSDs?

Comment: Anyway: using Finder is for sure slower than most other options. If you share details like mount points (aka which directory in `/Volumes` is which disk) somebody here for sure can help with the appropriate `rsync` options. But you can also play it safe and use CCC (as already mentioned by User mmmmmm).

Comment: My choice would be ChronoSync - it is very efficient at large scale data transfer.